# Loading icon hiding after window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript function which refreshes page one time after page load. To let the user know that it's loading, I have added a loading icon. It works fine but stops as soon as the page is loaded first time and doesn't show when the page is getting reloaded.

I want the loading icon to hide only after page is reloaded.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function () {
        if (window.localStorage) {
            if (!localStorage.getItem('firstLoad')) {
                localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else
                localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
            $("#loaderbox").hide();
        }
    })();
});
</script>
```

Loader icon code:

```
<div id="loaderbox">
<div class="loader_bg"></div>
<div class="loder_in">
    <div class="loader_wrapper">
        <div class="preloader-wrapper big active" style="width:102px;height:102px;">
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gap-patch">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="im_wrapper" style="left:6px;"><img src="/static/images/key.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should look into eventlisteners. Also, if you need to refresh the page (after its already loaded once) you maybe should try to change your approach of that behaviour. Dynamic loading is *always* (almost) preferred over page refreshes.It leaves the user confused as to what is going on.

Comment: If you remove `$("#loaderbox").hide();` - does the image remain?  Your description implies it's not shown before this, which would be caused by how the page is rendered initially.

Comment: @freedomn-m If I remove $("#loaderbox").hide(); then image remains.

Comment: Either put the `.hide` inside the else or add a `return;` after `.reload()` (which would also cover the case where localstorage is not available)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that

```
window.location.reload();
```

does not stop the execution of the script.

So you essentially have:

```
window.location.reload();
$("#loaderbox").hide();
```

so your loader box is always hidden before the reload completes (especially if it takes a few seconds which is likely otherwise you wouldn't need the load / notice it not being there).

You can test this in the console with:

```
window.location.reload(); alert("before reload");
```

which shows the alert before the reload occurs.

The fix is to add a `return` directly after the `reload()` to stop further execution (or adjust the position of the `.hide()` so it doesn't always run after the if-else.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function () {
        if (window.localStorage) {
            if (!localStorage.getItem('firstLoad')) {
                localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
                window.location.reload();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
                $("#loaderbox").hide();
            }
        }
    })();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use javascript to detect when the page has finished loading and remove the loading icon.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#yourImageId").remove();
});
```

Comment: Tried this but the image does not get removed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be closer to your original code.

Answer (score 0):

The function $(document).ready fired after complete the DOM.

Use this to execute a function after loaded the complete content (img etc.)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 console.log('All assets are loaded')
})
```

Comment: Unless the images are cached, which they will very likely be on a `location.reload()`